# Load jks file inside java APP (CXF)

Tags: java, ssl, soap, cxf, keystore

Hu Guys,

I am trying to call a SOAP Web server using CXF and certificate. I have the jks file and I tested it using SOAPUI, what is working properly. What I want is to load this JKS file the same way it is done by SOAPUI, instead os creating a certificate to put in my cacert file. I tried some options but none of them worked so far, because it never finds the certificate (unable to find valid certification path to requested target). Does anyone know a way to keep the jks file in some specific folder and load it only by the application, without impacting other apps?

What I need to do is load it, call the soap endpoint and validate, exactly as SOAPUI seems to be doing. I am sorry not putting any code, but it is a project under NDA.

I am running cxf 3.17 with java 1.8  on eclipse mars edition. Also importing the certificate using keytools is not an option for this scenario.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these JVM arguments to load jks from your desired path:

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\myname\Documents\mykeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

Comment: I have tried it and also loading the certficate via code, but even though my certificate is read by the application and set to the conduit it is still not recognized by the server. I am using as example this code: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/